# Where to place the check:noarg_temp_created option in Visual Studio?

Tags: fortran, visual-studio-2017

When using the debug mode, MS Visual Studio takes a lot of memory and time to create temporary files when reading from input files (in my case, tables of values used by some functions and subroutines from a library I need). My code is in modern fortran.

I know there is a flag that I can use that is equivalent to the check:noarg_temp_created for the command line, but I don't know where to specify it (a colleague showed me, but I cannot contact him due to the holidays). I tried a few places in the configuration properties, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Projects->Fortran->Run-time, the property is labeled:
"Check For Actual Arguments Using Temporary Storage".

Also, in general, if you know the command line spelling can't find the corresponding Visual Studio property, you can use the Project->Fortran->Command Line box to enter the command line itself.

Comment: Thanks, but that property is already set to "no" in the options. I keep getting the warning "forrtl: warning (406): fort: (1): In call to I/O Read routine, an array temporary was created for argument #1"

Comment: Also check the Command Line box Lorri mentioned to make sure the option is not being overridden. I've seen this warning before for an I/O statement, though, and asked the developers to fix it a few years ago. The response I got was "not a bug" - I disagreed because the user has no control over how the compiler implements I/O statements.

Comment: Both set as "no" in the run-time options and in the command line with the flag /check:noarg_temp_created. I made sure to rebuild the project, too, it worked.

Thanks.